# Ubuntu shows hard drive with a quarter of it's size

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption, luks

Ubuntu live stick (tried different versions: 14.04, 16.04, 17.04) shows my additional hard drive as 802GB which is roughly 750GiB, beeing a quarter of the 3TB of it's actual size. And I am unable to mount it.

Can that have anything to do with the block sizes? Drives this size don't usually have 512B blocks, but ubuntu probably assumes that....

GParted often gives the good old "driver says the blocksize is 2048B, but linux says it's 512B" warining.

To be a litle more specific:
It's actually two drives in RAID1 and they are encrypted with LUKS/dm-crypt, but I am able to unlock them, I just can't mount them:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/isw_hjgegijjc_RAID1 vault
Enter the passphrase for »/dev/mapper/isw_hjgegijjc_RAID1«: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/vault
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/vault /mnt/vault
Failed to read last sector (5860524030): invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/vault': invalid argument
The device '/dev/mapper/vault' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

The interesting thing is: it works fine with my current ubuntu installation (which is giving me some other trouble) and I am concerned of data loss in case I crash that one ubuntu installation.

lsblk does show the partition inside the LUKS container:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sdf                          8:80   0   2,7T  0 disk   
└─isw_hjgegijjc_RAID1      253:0    0 746,5G  0 dmraid 
  └─vault                  253:2    0 746,5G  0 crypt  
sdd                          8:48   0   2,7T  0 disk   
└─isw_hjgegijjc_RAID1      253:0    0 746,5G  0 dmraid 
  └─vault                  253:2    0 746,5G  0 crypt  
sdb                          8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk   
├─sdb1                       8:17   0 931,5G  0 part   
└─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0     253:1    0   1,8T  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0p2 253:4    0 109,4G  0 part   
  └─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0p1 253:3    0   1,7T  0 part   
sde                          8:64   1   7,5G  0 disk   /cdrom
├─sde2                       8:66   1   2,3M  0 part   
└─sde1                       8:65   1   1,5G  0 part   
loop0                        7:0    0   1,4G  1 loop   /rofs
sdc                          8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk   
└─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0     253:1    0   1,8T  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0p2 253:4    0 109,4G  0 part   
  └─isw_cebdbccfga_RAID0p1 253:3    0   1,7T  0 part   
sda                          8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk   
├─sda2                       8:2    0  77,4G  0 part   
├─sda5                       8:5    0  33,8G  0 part   
├─sda1                       8:1    0   100M  0 part   
└─sda6                       8:6    0     8G  0 part   [SWAP]
```